# What to do if my advisor insists on early attendance?

Tags: advisor, europe, health, france

I have a genuine problem in waking up early in the morning. My advisor prefers to walk in my office whenever he wanted to. Lately, he started to complain to me about not showing up in the morning. Even the way to
 he used to come to my office has changed, he started to open the door without knocking and then the first thing he checks my computer screen.

I tried to tell him that about my difficulties and suggested scheduling meetings instead. He told me these are the rules of the institution and I have to follow them.

Long story short, I started to come early in the morning but I can barely get anything done.

---

**Update 1**: I reviewed the contract, it explicitly mentioned that working time starts no later than 9am. My contract is with an institution not the university directly.

**Update 2** : I consulted a doctor and I have been diagnosed with depression. Besides the medication that was prescribed to me, I was asked to take a rest from the school.
Thank you, everyone, for sharing your thoughts.

Comment: Use a screensaver with a password.

Comment: Arriving at a particular time is one of the rules of the institution? According to whom?

Comment: Sounds like a control freak. I imagine his concern is you are not putting in the required number of hours. When would you leave if you came in late?

Comment: @ElizabethHenning I am afraid he is legally correct. It's considered a full time job.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm I feel that he assumed that I am careless and he did not want that to go unchecked. I usually spend 9 hours since my arrival.

Comment: @ASquare Sure, but are there really set times specified by the institution? If he gets to decide what your work hours are, why does he need you to come in mornings? Wouldn't he rather you were productive than sleep-deprived?

Comment: What does your contract say about working hours? Full time job does not imply any fixed hours afaik... I have flexible working hours despite working a full time job, it's common here (at least in Germany)

Comment: Can you please define "early attendance"? To me it seems like your advisor insists on working hours that would be considered normal outside academia. As a supervisor it is their duty to enforce regulations of the institution. Thus, you'll need to adjust.

Comment: I am so sorry for your situation - I doubt there's much you can do even if there is no official working hours; you have to comply with your advisers (objectively) reasonable requests - and unfortunately society does not accept "not a morning person" as reasonable (despite all the research done on it). Most places I've worked insisted on being there during "core hours" (e.g. 11am-3pm or similar), so anybody can catch anybody they need, which I find reasonable, but I still don't know how I'll manage a faculty position if I even manage to get one and need to be there at 9am.

Comment: @penelope If your university schedule lectures early in the morning, if you are the professor, you have to manage to go there on time. For instance, I frequently have lectures scheduled at 8:30 am and, no, I cannot ask for a more comfortable schedule (and given the morning traffic, since I commute, to avoid being late, I tend to arrive at 7:30-8). If you want a certain job, you adapt to the required conditions or you leave.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I understand that you can't be late for your fixed obligations, and that this is true for any job. I guess it would have been more factual to say "I'm still dreading the schedule shift I will need to manage if I ever get a faculty position" or even "I still don't have a clear picture of how I'll manage and I know it is going to be difficult for me." rather than "I still don't know how I'll manage it". Not knowing exactly how I will adapt, or dreading that change (which I do), is different from not accepting that I have to adapt or refusing to follow the rules (which I don't).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Really don't want to sound rude or confrontational, but I am quite surprised that my comment made you write such a stern and strict comment about "You have to be on time for your job obligations, even if they are early. You can not ask to make it more comfortable. If you can not adapt, you have to leave." I never even hinted at having a habit of being late for morning events - was just mentioning that I (passionately) dislike them. I think disliking one aspect of your job should not be a reason to suggest that you are not suited for that job and should leave.

Comment: Schools typically do give "normal working hours" for staff, and often consider postdocs as staff. The school typically also will denote the advisor as supervisor meaning they do have the power to set your working hours (within reason and laws).

Comment: @penelope Sorry, when it comes to work schedule, I frequently react sternly because it's a problem I had with a lot of PhD students, and many comments that usually arrive here with this type of questions reflect too much the very narrow view of fields like mathematics or computer science, where a PhD student can work with a relatively free schedule, but not that of other fields where the coordination with colleagues is much more essential. Not too mention industry, where actually the majority of PhD students will end up anyway.

Comment: @penelope At my school there is no problem asking for later times for your courses. Especially if you are willing to be flexible in other ways. I wouldn't bring it up during the interviews, of course. And indeed I'd wait until after tenure to let them know you'd prefer to sleep till noon everyday. But academia is nothing if not vastly more flexible than a "real job". Certainly the scheduling isn't the part you  should dread. Also staying awake to deliver a lecture is vastly easier than staying awake while listening to one.

Comment: @ASimpleAlgorithm Out of curiosity, how many students does your school have overall?

Comment: Let me make a remark after your update: regardless of contracts, it's fundamental when you start to work in a new place to understand and adapt to the work culture of the place. If you see that every time you arrive, everyone else is already at work... well ;-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As a fellow night owl, I feel your pain. Normally I would suggest concisely explaining your difficulties and suggesting a work-around to your advisor, but it sounds like you've already done that. Sadly, your advisor does have the right to set working hours, so **you have no real recourse** other than finding a different advisor.

The situation might be different if you have a medical diagnosis/disability -- but I don't think "night owl" will qualify, since waking up early is not harmful to your health (not sure about French law though). What I've done in similar situations is to use melatonin to fall asleep early and caffeine pills to wake up -- probably not the healthiest solution long-term, but it does the trick for me.

Comment: Thank you, I never thought about taking sleep bills. May I ask about how do you feel when you wake up after taking melatonin?

Comment: I can't tell any difference by morning, it's out of my system by then (so long as you sleep for more than a few hours). OTOH, even if I've had "enough" sleep, I'm still not wakeful in the morning (hence the caffeine pills).

Comment: Taking medication to meet an advisor's expectations... What a time to be alive...

Comment: I didn't recommend it, I said that's what I do....though "show up at 9 AM" is hardly an unreasonable or unusual expectation.

Comment: While "night owl" might not be a medical disability, do you by chance have severe trouble sleeping, such as insomnia? I had a friend during my PhD in your situation, and the biggest problem for her is that sometimes she would not even fall asleep before morning, and then had to wake up in an hour to meet the schedule expectations. So you have similar problems, that could potentially be officially diagnosed as a medical condition. But - I feel you - I was the first runner up for the (joke & sarcastic) prize of "Early Bird" in my lab - lost to a friend who was late for lunch more often than me.

Comment: _Sadly, your advisor does have the right to set working hours_ - Why is this?  Also, if it possibly is a medical issue, @ASquare should consult with a medical professional.

Comment: @Kimball Because in some countries a PhD student is considered an employee and the advisor is the "boss", who can also fire you if your working hours don't meet their expectations.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I understand this may be true in some situations, but I don't understand why it is necessarily true in the OP's situation, as this answer seems to assert.

Comment: It's the professor's lab and the professor's research funds, they can impose whatever rules they want, so long as it doesn't contradict the law or university policy. I seriously doubt "show up at 9 AM" would be overturned upon appeal to a dean or judge, even if the working hours could easily be shifted three hours later (could be different if OP has a medical diagnosis, or if they want him to show up at 3 AM and work 19-hour days, but no indication that is the case here).

Comment: @penelope It could be the case since no matter who I try to correct my schedule I just can't fell asleep

Comment: "your advisor does have the right to set working hours". To clarify: no they don't. The working hours are set by your institutions and probably spelled out in your contract. Your advisor can insist on your observance of these hours, but they can't impose hours of their own choosing.

Comment: This does not seem like a "clarification" but rather "completely disagreeing" -- consider posting an answer that justifies your viewpoint. As I said, professors' policies cannot "contradict the law or university policy," so if university policy does specify working hours, then we don't disagree. In my experience, however, such policies are not typical because requirements are so diverse. For example, it is reasonable to expect astronomers to work at night, or to schedule extra meetings before an important deadline.

Answer (score 3):

> He told me these are the rules of the institution and I have to follow them.

I've done my PhD and two postdocs in three different universities in France and I've never heard of such rules. On the contrary, my experience is that the standard in academia working hours is whatever works for you.

The problem is to avoid a confrontation with your advisor, as you probably don't want to have a bad relation with them. You could try a slowdown strategy (*grève du zèle*): you abide by their rules but you follow all the rules, that is working no more than the legal 35 hours a week, not answering emails or doing anything outside working hours, etc. Hopefully after a few weeks of this your advisor will realize that it's better to let you decide yourself how to organize your working time.

I'd say that's the French way to deal with it... sorry for the stereotype ;)

Comment: Or, you will create an even worse relationship between you and your advisor, who may then proceed to not let you graduate.

Comment: I don't see why, somebody who insists on you applying the rules can't honestly blame you later for doing so.

Comment: @Erwan You're using logic, but this isn't a question of logic (even in France). This is an issue of control, which is fundamentally emotional.

Comment: I am carrying out my work in an institution not a university. As @penelope pointed out this might make things wors.

Comment: @JeffE Before talking about emotions, you may want to read the update to the OP.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano And why do _you_ think that clause is in the contract?

Comment: @JeffE As I just wrote in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50116885#50116885), I'm frequently puzzled here by the lack of understanding of how certain tasks require a coordination that doesn't allow you to choose your own working schedule but requires you to adapt to a group schedule, whether you like it or not. This narrow view is certainly due to the fact that most of the users here are theorists (mathematicians, computer scientists etc.), but from experienced users (like you), I would expect a broader view.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano But in those situations, the boss wouldn't just say "Show up early because those are the rules", but rather "Key steps in the the experiment need to be done a certain schedule." or "Critical tasks like [examples] require everyone on the team to have the same schedule." Riiight?  I'm well aware that such circumstances exist, but my default association with "my way or the highway" is not "they have a good reason" but "they're a control freak".

Comment: @JeffE From a PhD student, one may expect the maturity to understand independently whether they should respect a certain schedule, and may react badly when such an expectation is not met.I don't, and I usually try to explain things (almost) nicely to my students, but I can imagine that someone can react harshly, especially if the schedule is written in the contract.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano I think you are missing the main point that is my coginitive abililty decreases if I enforce certain sleep schedule, I  will hardly make any progress. It's not something I have control over but it seems some people can't grasp this.  I am working alone and there is no consistency in my advisors random check up, so I have to be on alert all day long rather having fixed time for meeting then off to sleep.

Comment: @ASquare I've been suffering from insomnia my whole life and even though I can manage the lack of sleep well, I know what it means to work sleep-deprived. For your advisor to have such a reaction, I think that there's more to the story than what's told in your post. For instance, he may get in trouble with the institution if he allows you to arrive late; or he may think that you've not been productive enough anyway even when you were arriving late. I think that at this point, you should have a very frank conversation with your advisor to understand where the core problem is.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of jobs where you have designated hours. One of the nice things about grad school is a bit more freedom on hours (at the cost of drastically lower pay).  But my advice is to just start working normal hours.

You CAN do this.  Start going to be bed earlier (take a hot bath to help).  Also start exercising in the late afternoon, early evening (before dinner, before getting diverted to TV or Internet).  A little bit of physical tiredness helps with making it easier to get to sleep.

Comment: It's not that easy. Most of us owls, I'm fairly sure, are not just larks with a shifted schedule. We need the night hours to get things done that we are unable to force ourselves to do during the day (e.g., because they are painful and anti-rewarding and we procrastinate them whenever we believe we have enough time left). If you take our night hours away, these things will just not get done, even if it will probably be better for our health. This holds for exercise in particular: I leave the hardest stuff to be done after exercising; but after exercising I'm so tired that I just drop to bed.

Comment: I say this as an owl myself.  However, if you were in the military standing a watch or doing some high paid shift work job, you would make the hours work.  So adapt and overcome.  No rest for the wicked.

Comment: People adapt at the cost of effectiveness (ask the students in my 9AM class). Standing a watch doesn't count, as 98% of the work is idling (and for the remaining 2%, humans have probably evolved for short-notice short-term mobilization).

Comment: @darijgrinberg, Let's be honest, the students who aren't paying attention in your 9 AM class have probably just been up half the night... I was a student and a night owl too during my studies, but that simply had to change when I started my first proper job. Not saying that the change is fun or easy, but doable.

Comment: @fgysin: I wasn't talking about the students being half asleep (though many of them are, too...). People in academia inhabit very different places on the tradeoff space between self-discipline and creativity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working at my third postdoc, which is a collaboration between a company and a university, and I am based at the company.

I am required to keep the company's hours; they do have flexi-time, but considering the core hours are between 9am and 4pm, it's not that handy. When I started, I decided to work 8am to 4pm, to avoid a busy and stressful commute.

This was a bit of a change from my previous postdoc, and I've found the best way to implement it is by sticking to a schedule - wake up at the same time, catch the same bus to and from work, leave at the same time. Not massively exciting, perhaps, but it's working for now.

I do feel this sort of schedule is, to some extent, a detriment to creativity and efficiency, but thems the rules.

Answer (score -4):

The advisor of my first postdoc also demanded this... The point is, if he doesn't respect your needs and instills this torture from you just because he can, he is probably unhappy about something else, thinks you are lazy, or just is a dick. And you torturing yourself is just not worth it. Better leave. I so much wish I left that first postdoc boss ...

Comment: I am not sure that leaving now is the best course of action